# Code First Fluent API, how can I?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

How can i do my fluent api in EF4.1 code first for this?

```
    public class employee
    {
        public int employeeId{ get; set; }
        public string name{ get; set; }
    }

    public class employeeDeparment
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public int employeeId{ get; set; }
        public int bossId{ get; set; }
        public int DeparmentId{ get; set; }    

        public virtual employee employees { get; set; }
        public virtual employee boss { get; set; }
        public virtual deparment deparments{ get; set; }
    }

    public class deparment
    {
        public int deparmetId{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

try this but dont work

```
modelBuilder.Entity<deparment>()
                   .HasOptional(c => c.boss )
                   .WithMany()
                   .HasForeignKey(c => c.bossId);
```

how it look in the database

edit:
database correct
http://subir-imagenes.es/?v=bdcorrect.png

Comment: It looks like your database model is incorrect because there are two FKs in `Deparment` side. Can you describe the relationships between these two entities.

Comment: when iam traing to achieve this is a example a bad example (for the hurry) but imagine that I want a employee can work in many deparment and may have several boss in each department that he work 
this is the correct
http://subir-imagenes.es/?v=bdcorrect.png

Comment: Take your time and build a database model that make sense. Try to model that using fluent API. There are plenty of articles out there. If you have specific problem then ask.

Comment: sorry about that. but iam spanish speaker so is all in spanish so i try to make a example in english for it would more understandable for people can understand me and help me. i have edit my question now, if you can help me, and what I want is that a employee can work in many deparment and can have a boss in any deparment a employee work. i could not get  and example in my specific case

Answer (score 0):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeDeparment>().HasMany(x => x.Employees)
    .WithRequired(x => x.EmployeeDepartment).HasForeignKey(x => x.EmployeeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<EmployeeDeparment>().HasMany(x => x.Bosses)
    .WithRequired(x => x.EmployeeDepartment).HasForeignKey(x => x.bossId);
```

other solution would be that you dont define middle table (it will be created by EF)

```
public class employee
{
    public int employeeId{ get; set; }
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public ICollection<department> departments { get;set; }
}

public class deparment
{
    public int deparmetId{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<employee> employees { get;set; }
    public ICollection<employee> bosses { get;set; }
}
```